# Using php class property in smarty template

Tags: php, arrays, class, smarty

Can i use php class static properties in smarty template?
For example:

```
class UserData
{
    const INDEX = 1;
    const STREET = 2;

    static public $_address_fields = array(
        self::INDEX,
        self::STREET 
    );
}
```

And in my smarty template i want do something like this:

```
{UserData::$_address_fields}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: as @u_mulder says, have you actually tried this?  If you have and it's giving errors or not working as expected then let us know what the problem is.

Comment: @TheMook  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'UserData' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass this in from your controller

For example:
`$smarty->assign('AddressFields, UserData::$_address_fields);`

This should then be available for use in your template like so:
`{$AddressFields}`

Smarty Docs:
https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.assign.tpl